# 最小二乗法の重付けでポワソン回帰を確認できるのでしょうか（Rプログラム）

Tags: r

こちらのサイト[ポワソン回帰](https://oku.edu.mie-u.ac.jp/%7Eokumura/stat/poisson_regression.html)を拝見させていただき、Rで実装しながら勉強しています。

等価な方法「その3」として、以下が紹介されています。これは、link関数がidentityの場合ですが、link関数がlogの場合も可能なのでしょうか。

```
x = c(1,2,3,4)
y = c(2,3,5,4)
w = c(1,1,1,1)
for (i in 1:10) {
  r = lm(y ~ x, weights=w)
  lambda = predict(r)
  print(c(as.numeric(r$coef), -sum(y*log(lambda)-lambda)))
  w = 1 / lambda
}
#省略
#[1]  1.2783467  0.8886613 -4.0609501

glm(y~x,family=poisson(link="identity"))
#(Intercept)            x  
#     1.2784       0.8887
```

以下、link関数をlogを想定して、単純にyをlog(y)に、wをlambdaにしてみましたが、違うのでしょうか。どなたかアドバイスをお願いしてもよろしいでしょうか。

```
x = c(1,2,3,4)
y = c(2,3,5,4)
w = c(1,1,1,1)
for (i in 1:10) {
  r = lm(log(y) ~ x, weights=w)
  lambda = predict(r)
  print(c(as.numeric(r$coef), -sum(y*log(lambda)-lambda)))
  w = lambda
}
#省略
#[1] 0.6195090 0.2334289 1.7332280

glm(y~x,family=poisson(link="log"))
#(Intercept)            x  
#     0.6393       0.2320
```

###################### 追加投稿 20200619 ######################

user12399423さん（回答日時: 6月13日13:19）
ご回答いただき、ありがとうございました。分かりやすい説明で、ずっと疑問に思っていたことが分かり、すっきりしました。勉強不足でお恥ずかしいですが、もう1点、同じようなことで分からないことがあり、もしまだこの質問が生きていたら、アドバイスを頂けると幸いです。
こちらのサイト[IRLS で解く最尤推定量](https://stats.biopapyrus.jp/glm/mle-irls.html)も拝見させていただき、勉強していました。

以下の加重最小二乗法では、link関数がlogの場合です。例えば、こちらのプログラムでidentityの場合（単純にlambdaの項からexpを削除した場合）は、可能なのでしょうか。実行してみると、うまくいきません（回帰分析と同じになる？）。なぜ、この場合は、link関数をlogにするとポワソン回帰になるのでしょうか。
混乱してしまいました。どなたかアドバイスをお願いしてもよろしいでしょうか。

```
#log
x<-c(1,2,3,4)
X<-cbind(rep(1, length(x)),x)
Y<-c(2,3,5,4)
beta <- matrix(0, ncol = 2, nrow = 100)
beta[1, ] <- c(1, 10)
for (m in 2:100) {
  lambda <- exp(X %*% beta[m - 1, ])
  W <- diag(lambda[, 1])
  XtWX <- t(X) %*% W %*% X
  U <- t(Y - lambda) %*% X
  beta[m, ] <- beta[m - 1, ] + solve(XtWX) %*% t(U)
}
tail(beta)
# [100,] 0.6392647 0.2320399#OK
```

これは、どうなのでしょうか。。

```
#identity?
x<-c(1,2,3,4)
X<-cbind(rep(1, length(x)),x)
Y<-c(2,3,5,4)
beta <- matrix(0, ncol = 2, nrow = 100)
beta[1, ] <- c(1, 10)
for (m in 2:100) {
  lambda <- (X %*% beta[m - 1, ])
  W <- diag(lambda[, 1])
  XtWX <- t(X) %*% W %*% X
  U <- t(Y - lambda) %*% X
  beta[m, ] <- beta[m - 1, ] + solve(XtWX) %*% t(U)
}
tail(beta)
# [100,] 1.499999 0.8000007
```

glmを実行する。

```
#glm
summary(glm(y~x))
#            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
#(Intercept)   1.5000     1.1619   1.291    0.326
#x             0.8000     0.4243   1.886    0.200
```

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://teratail.com/questions/263729

Answer (score 0):

違います. 元の方法はリンク関数が恒等写像のときに y = lambda = a * x + b になることを利用しているので, リンク関数を対数に設定すると成り立ちません(その1, その2も良い近似にならないと思います). そしてお考えの方法では極値で成り立つのが log(lambda) * (log(y) - 1) * lambda' * exp(lambda) = 0 となり, ポアソン回帰の尤度の1階条件とはかけ離れてしまっています. ちなみに `lambda = exp(predict(r))` とすると比較的近い値が出ますが, 多分 lambda の値があまり変化しないことによる偶然だと思います

Comment: user12399423さん、ご回答くださり、どうもありがとうございました。わかる人がなかなかいなかったので、貴重なご説明を大変嬉しく思います。でも、まだ混乱しているところがあり、質問を更新しました。もしも、まだこの質問が生きていましたら、見に来ていただけると、嬉しく思います。